# HTTP 415 error when using HttpOutboundGateway with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am building a simple Spring integration app which reads CSV files from a directory, turns them into XML documents and sends them to a system via a REST XML web service.

The integration flow looks something like this:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="filesChannel" ... />

<int:channel id="filesChannel" />
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="resultChannel" />

<int:chain input-channel="filesChannel" output-channel="resultChannel">
    <!-- Parse the CSV into individual messages of Map<String,String> type -->
    <int:transformer ref="csvToMapsTransformer" method="transform" />
    <int:splitter />

    <!-- Transform the map into a simple XML -->
    <int:transformer ref="mapToXmlTransformer" method="transform" />

    <!-- Use XSLT template to transform the simple XML into the API format -->
    <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="order-api-transform.xslt" />

    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <!-- Post the XML to the target system -->
    <int-http:outbound-gateway 
        http-method="POST" 
        url="http://example.com/method"
        expected-response-type="javax.xml.transform.Source" 
         />
</int:chain>
```

The `mapToXmlTransformer` is a simple loop over Map entries which builds an XML string with a StringBuilder. Then this XML string is transformed with XSLT to a format the target system expects.

The flow works pretty much as I am expecting it to. It sends the payload in a POST request to the target system, but it returns an HTTP 415 response:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Cannot consume content type
```

It seems like I am doing a simple stupid mistake with my flow, but I am new to Spring Integration and cannot find it myself.

Please help

Comment: The target system might expect `application/xml` instead of `text/xml` and be very strict about this. Info: `application/xml` is also valid and defines media types that are not readable (vague definition) to humans.

Comment: Hi @meistermeier. You were right, the application did actually expect `application/xml`, but that was not the only problem. A combination of your and Gary's advice helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spring messaging content type message header is `contentType`, not `Content-Type`.

See `MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE` - it is mapped to the Http `Content-Type` header.

You can use the constant via SpEL:

```
<header name="#{T(org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders).CONTENT_TYPE}" 
        value="text/xml" />
```

or just use `name="contentType"`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Also, @meistermeier was also right. So when I applied the "contentType" name and "application/xml" value - all worked! Thank you